# What is a "magnetic shaped charge"

Tags: meaning, terminology

Just reading this article and in one of the first sentences it says:

> A few days ago, 32-year-old Mostafa Ahmadi Roshan died in his car,
>   after two motorcyclists attached a magnetic shaped charge to the door.

I'm trying to understand what "magnetic shaped" means or what is a "magnetic shaped charge", if it is some special term?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A magnetic shaped charge is a charge (explosive device) whose explosion is shaped (by some mechanism) and is attached to the car by a magnet.

So the object is a [*shaped charge*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaped_charge) and it is modified by the adjective *magnetic*.

Comment: Er, are you sure the magnetic field actually shapes the charge? I would take it to mean it is a standard *shaped charge* and the *magnetic* modifier is simply how the charge is attached to the target.

Comment: This is not the answer. It is a shaped charge attached to the car using magnets

Comment: Well, no I can't be certain. I'm not sure which interpretation is more likely.

Comment: @horatio I've updated the answer

Comment: I think if it was a charge that was shaped by a magnetic field it would be a magnetical_ly_ shaped charge.

Comment: _[Shaped charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaped_charge)_ is a  fixed phrase of long standing. It has nothing to do with magnetic fields.

Comment: The downvote is misguided. Matt *hasn't* claimed the charge is *shaped by a magnetic field*. Effectively the opposite, since he says *shaped by some device*. And as John says, *shaped charge* is a long-established "fixed phrase".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: He isn't claiming it now, but he did claim it originally -- see the edits (not my downvote, by the way).

Comment: @John: oic. Well, no matter - it's corrected now, and this is the only answer needed. Perhaps the downvoter will come back sometime and reverse it.

Comment: It looks like [this article](http://englishqna.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-is-magnetic-shaped-charge.html) is a ripoff of this question and answer.

Answer (score 4):

Matt is correct.  This is a shaped charge that attaches via a magnet; as opposed to a *magnetically* shaped charge, which would indicate a charge that gets its shape magnetically.

Answer (score 2):

No. The magnet is used to attach the bomb to the vehicle. Then the “shaped charge” is referencing the way the explosive material is arranged to explode: focussing much of the energy into a small space.

An example would be a bomb, itself probably the size of a hockey puck, but which left a hole the size of a dime, for an example. It releases molten copper and incinerates everything inside the vehicle. Shaped charges are used to pierce armor.

Two separate components.

God bless the USA.